# How can I improve performance of BigInteger as compiled to Objective C by Xamarin.iOS / Mono?

Tags: ios, performance, xamarin.ios, cryptography, bouncycastle

The following performance trace indicates a performance bottleneck in Bouncy Castle when compiled for Xamarin iOS

[image]

Are there any better ways I can re-implement this specific function to take better advantage of iOS hardware?

Right now Bouncy Castle creates a BigInt on top of Mono abstractions, on top of iOS code.  The end result is probably under-optimized.

What is the fastest way to do Big Int operations on iOS?

Here is the link to the [relevant Bouncy Castle source](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/bb2b60811f0010ff0bff4a1acdd866087c179073/crypto/src/math/BigInteger.cs#L1930)

Comment: A multiprecision biginteger package is a huge undertaking. I suspect the question as asked is too broad. However, the usual way to speed up public key operations is to use native libraries. At the very least, you should examine the performance of a native library for a similar task so you have some sense of what reasonable performance looks like

Comment: I can't find any reference to 'square monty' on the inter webs. But there are a couple of things that spring to mind. Firstly that screen shot looks to me like someone ran some Java code through an iOS converter. I never trust code produced by converters. It's usually no-where near as good as a properly built API. Second, before looking at 3rd party APIs, check to make sure that the builtin APIs don't already do what you need. 3rd party APIs might make coding easier, but they not always the best choice.

Comment: Are you working with real-time audio cryptography? I can figure out many cases were iOS `BigInt` library would be a bottleneck. Remember that native libraries also must be correctly compiled because they rely on compiler optimization flags.

Comment: I'm doing cryptography, which is the same CPU intensity. I need to find those flags